# Is there any way to view css errors in ie11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Say I have misprint in my css:
`div { lolor: led; }`

Chrome will display following messages in console:
`Invalid CSS property name: lolor`

How can I view something like this in IE11?

Answer (score 3):

Press F12

This site should help you a little: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx

Honestly though they just use this to validate your CSS values: [W3C Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) (link fixed)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the F12 tool will only show the css property underlined in red in the styles properties of the element but you will not have any message in the console.